# How to include multiple files in a git repo config?

Tags: git, include, git-config

I want to [include](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) multiple config files in a Git repo config. However, when I run multiple commands like

```
git config include.path /path/to/config/file
```

only the last path is saved in the config. Does Git support multiple includes? If yes, how to include multiple files from the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--add` option

```
git config --add include.path config1.txt
git config --add include.path config2.txt
```

```
$ git config --get-all include.path
config1.txt
config2.txt
```